# Facebook ui share method displays small thumbs when shared from mobile

Tags: facebook, user-interface, share

I'm using FB.ui share method to share links on Facebook.I have to use this method since I want to tag friends on my post.

window.open(
            'https://www.facebook.com/v2.1/dialog/share?app_id=&display=popup&redirect_uri='+encodeURIComponent(REDIRECT_URL)+'url='+encodeURIComponent(SHARE_LINK),
          'facebook-share-dialog', 
           'width=750,height=393');

Even though my og:image has the right size, i.e 1200x630px when shared on Facebook the shared link is displayed with small thumb.

When I change the method to FEED dialog or SHARE using facebook/...//sharer.php URL large thumb is shown for the shared link on Facebook.
window.open(
            'https://www.facebook.com/v2.2/dialog/feed?app_id=&display=popup&redirect_uri='+encodeURIComponent(REDIRECT_URL)+'&link='+encodeURIComponent(''),
            'facebook-share-dialog', 
            'width=750,height=393'); 
            return false;"

IS there any additional parameter that I need to add TO https://www.facebook.com/v2.1/dialog/share so my image is displayed correctly I.E with large thumb on Facebook?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exactly same issue. I was using "/sharer/sharer" for sharing links and everything was working well. And when I try to use the "/v2.1//dialog/share" I noticed that on desktop, images are big (1200 width) but on mobile (web and iOS App), the share is displayed as a small square.

I think it is because when you use "/v2.1/dialog/share", Facebook assume you share a story through your Facebook App and on mobile UI, story are displayed with small square image :-(

When you use the /sharer/sharer, there is no association with your app and Facebook will just assume user share a link in his feed. And it is the only type of share that display large image on all platform (desktop, mobile and iOS app)

So basically I don't think you can force FB to display large image :-(.

The Facebook [doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images) say that providing big image will result in big image display but it looks like it is only the case for desktop. And for mobile only link status are displayed as big image.